# Exclude a CSS file in Visual Studio's Theme folder

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, sass

I'm just starting to play with SASS in Visual Studio. The question I have is that if I put my .scss file in the theme folder, the compiled CSS file will automatically be added to the site. The problem comes in that it generates a .css AND a .min.css file and BOTH are being applied to pages that use the theme.

Is there a way to have VS only add the .min.css automatically? I'd love to keep them in the theme folder and let VS handle linking everything automatically, but I don't want the stylesheet to be added twice. Or is there something else that is considered better/best practice that I should be doing with SASS files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Web Essentials plugin to compile SASS? If yes, in its options, you can change it so when it compiles it can output min, css or either.

example for LESS (same for SASS):

[image]

Plus, even if VS is producing min and css files, it wouldn't make much difference since bundling will only use one file. You can just exclude certain files from the solution, and they will be ignored.

You could also look at build tools such as Gulp or Grunt to compile sass - they have much more options that you can apply.

Comment: Yes, I am using web essentials and I had see these options, I was wondering if there were any other way to set a filter on the folder. I think this may really be the only way to do it. I'll have to check and see what the bundler is doing when I play run the project. Thanks.